# Android Studio 4.1.3. Show Baseline Contextual Menu Option not available

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, baseline

I am a newbie to Android Studio. I'm going through the Android Kotlin google [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-constraint-layout/index.html#9) .

In step 3, "Step 3: Align the baselines of the two text views", I'm told to click on the textview I just added and use the edit baseline icon. I don't have one and googled that it's deprecated and I should use the right-click contextual menu. Except I don't have a Show Baseline option for either of the textviews I just added. Above I do have a bunch of chained textviews and they DO have a Show Baseline option. I've googled this and the few references I found just insist there should be a right-click Show Baseline option. What am I not understanding?

Snapshot one
[image]

Snapshot two
[image]

Comment: Just to note, that I added the baseline XML manually as in 

        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/info_text"

and now the right-click contextual menu contains a Show Baseline option. Must be a bug is my best guess at this point.